# git addfilepattern can't read my directory path

Tags: java, git, ant, jgit

I have wrote a custom git-add ant task and I want it to add files only from stated directory.
The task line looks like this:

```
<gitadd repository="./project" dir="./project/src"/>
```

And here is how I add using jgit
I get dir like this:

```
public void setDir(String dir) {
    this.dir = dir;
    }
```

And I add it like this:

```
Repository repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder().readEnvironment()
        .findGitDir(repository).build();
Git git = new Git(repo);
AddCommand add = git.add();
add.addFilepattern(dir).call();
```

The task works fine when i use `addFilepattern(".")` instead of `addFilepattern(dir)`

How should i pass my directory path to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are not passing a repository-relative path to `addFilepattern`. See [the documentation of addFilepattern](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.html#addFilepattern%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

From your example, it looks like your task should look like this instead:

```
<gitadd repository="./project" dir="src"/>
```

Comment: I can't believe i missed it. Thank you!